# Ember JS creating a "private" function inside controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an ember controller which has some actions. Inside those actions I want to be able to call another function to regroup functionality but I don't want to do it through `this.send('someAction')`, I just want to call it directly and not have anything except that controller call that function.

```
actions: {
  my_btn_click: function(){
    this.set('somthing', 'something else');
    //functionA call here, not this.send('something');
  }
},
//declare functionA here ? doesnt work.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ember objects are just extensions to plain JS objects, meaning you can define methods on them and call them (through `this`) as you would on regular objects:

```
functionA: function() {

}

actions: {
  my_btn_click: function(){
    this.functionA();
  }
},
```

Comment: exactly, i missed the 'this'